# connecting to socket.IO server through apache webproxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, socket.io

I have 2 node.js apps on my vps. One on port 3001 and one on port 5001(ssl) and 5000(http).

I use apache proxy to route traffic from the homepage to the node.js Servers. it also allows me to easily install a LE certificate.

This is my apache setup

```
    ProxyPass /herstelling http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse /herstelling http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPass /kaaswijn http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse /kaaswijn http://localhost:3001/
```

The site loads, but I'm unable to get my socket.io to connect.
This is the code I'm using

In order to get https working i set up a domain cdn.quintenverhelst.be to get a certificate.

This domain just points directly to the server IP

On the nodeJS Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var port = 5000;
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

---

```
https.createServer({
//server keys
}, app).listen(5001);
```

Client side connecting code:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.quintenverhelst.be:5001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>   
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script> var socket = io.connect("https://cdn.quintenverhelst.be:5001");</script>
    <script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/verhelstq/maintenanceReport/engine.js"></script>
```

When I open this it gives me the error:

socket.io.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

The URL does not resolve to the socket.io.js file. Looks like its not even loading socket IO script into the page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.quintenverhelst.be:5001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Try removing the port number, the JS file resolved when I tested on my end.

```
<script src="https://cdn.quintenverhelst.be/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

That should get you at least past this first error.